# Starting thin webserver in different ways

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin

I use 'thin' webserver for rails application development. There are different ways to launch the thin server. Curious to know if there is any difference in launching the server in each of the following way: Is there any pros or cons.

a. `thin start`
I can provide various thin specific parameters during startup for example ssl options. But I am not sure how to provide such start up parameters in the rest of the following methods.

b. `rails s` (Note: thin is provided in the gem file)

c. `rackup`
I find `rackup` starts the server in port 9292, while other methods starts the server in 3000

d. Start thin from IDE. For example IDE such as Rubymine (that I use) has a convenient way for launching the server with different configuration such as Run / Debug.

One obvious advantage I find launching the server using IDE is that debugging is quite seamless. At the same time am not sure how to pass 'thin' start up specific parameters such as ssl options.(this is rubymine specific. Would be glad if anyone has an idea on this. Thanks !)

(Guess this question is applicable to any webserver used with rails. But I have raised the question in the context of 'thin' since I am currently using it).

Answer (score 0):

IMO, all those methods do the same.

a. `thin start` is a command that can be used if you are not using a Rack based framework.

b. `rails s` proxies to the `rackup` command. [rails server source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/commands/server.rb)

c. `rackup` is a command to start Rack-based applications that have a `config.ru` file. This file usually contains the configuration for the server.

d. I haven't used RubyMine specifically but I'm guessing it is similar to the above options.

[TR;DR]

e. There is one more way(actually, two more): By using thin as a backend server behind nginx. This setup is usually used in production environments to get better throughput. The Nginx server receives an incoming request and sends it to the thin instances running behind it. This again, has two ways of configuration:

1. Normal Thin + Nginx configuration where several thin instances are started up and they receive the requests from nginx directly.
2. Thin + Nginx + Unix sockets configuration where the Nginx server and each of the Thin instances share a unix socket. So, the path of the request would be: Interwebs -> Nginx -> Unix socket -> Thin and the response follows a similar pattern.

You can read more about thin, its configuration (and nginx) here: https://github.com/macournoyer/thin